# Combine SQL Select and AVG in one query

Tags: sql, select, average

I try to combine a `SELECT` and an `AVG` query into one. My query is working but the `AVG` result is not shown as expected. Error is:

> Undefined index

I thought I can combine `AVG` and `SELECT` like this?

the result will be a list and should also show an average progress value. If I put this AVG query separately and inside the "fetch" it works but shows only the first result. So it is not a solution for me because I will have much more rows.

I hope someone can help me to rebuild this miracle :)

```
<?php

  $statement = $pdo->prepare("        
    SELECT
      audit.id as audit_id, 
      audit.uid, 
      audit.assigned_auditor, 
      audit.audit_req_comment, 
      audit.audit_req_date, 
      audit.audit_date_start, 
      audit.general_audit_status, 
      audit.audit_request_date,
      audit.audit_type, 
      audit.audit_date_start,
      questionaire.quest_name, 
      users.nachname,    
      suppliers.supplier_name, 
      suppliers.supplier_city,
      suppliers.supplier_country,
      (SELECT AVG(progress) AS progress FROM answers WHERE relevant = '1' AND audit_id = :audit_id AND rating != required_answer)
    FROM audit 
    JOIN users ON audit.uid = users.id 
    JOIN suppliers ON audit.supplier_id = suppliers.id 
    JOIN questionaire ON audit.questionaire_id = questionaire.id 
    WHERE 
      audit.cid = :cid 
      AND audit.general_audit_status = 'Maßnahmenplan'
      AND audit.assigned_auditor = :assigned_auditor"
  );

  $result = $statement->execute(array(':cid' => $cid, ':assigned_auditor' => $user['id'], ':audit_id' => 4));
  $count = 1;
  while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {

    // Datum umwandeln
    $original_date = $row['audit_date_start'];
    // Creating timestamp from given date
    $timestamp = strtotime($original_date);
    // Creating new date format from that timestamp
    $new_date = date("d.m.Y", $timestamp);

    // Audit Typ Namensgebung
    if ($row['audit_type'] == "AR") {
      $audit_type = "Externes Audit";
    }
    if ($row['audit_type'] == "RA") {
      $audit_type = "Remote Audit";
    }
    if ($row['audit_type'] == "IA") {
      $audit_type = "Internes Audit";
    }
    if ($row['audit_type'] == "SAA") {
      $audit_type = "Self Assessment Audit";
    }

    //Berechne die durchschnittliche Abarbeitung aller Maßnahmen dieses Audits
    //$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT AVG(progress) AS progress FROM answers WHERE relevant = '1' AND    audit_id = :audit_id AND rating != required_answer");
    //$statement->execute(array(':audit_id' => $row['audit_id']));
    //$total_progress = $statement->fetch();

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['audit_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $new_date . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['supplier_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['supplier_city'] . " (" . $row['supplier_country'] . ")</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quest_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $audit_type . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . round($row['progress'], 0) . " %</td>";
    echo '<td align="center"><a href="audit_edit.php?id=' . $row['audit_id'] . '"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>';

    echo "</tr>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Putting subselects in the select area of a query isn't my preference/taste, but it will work/is a valid and acceptable thing to do

Comment: Is it on purpose that your main query and your subquery are two separate things, i.e. not correlated? Don't you rather want to show progess for the user or the questionaire you are showing in your main query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you just need to *alias* the results of the subquery in the outer query (rather than in the inner query itself):

```
SELECT
    audit.id as audit_id, 
    audit.uid, 
    audit.assigned_auditor, 
    audit.audit_req_comment, 
    audit.audit_req_date, 
    audit.audit_date_start, 
    audit.general_audit_status, 
    audit.audit_request_date,
    audit.audit_type, 
    audit.audit_date_start,
    questionaire.quest_name, 
    users.nachname,    
    suppliers.supplier_name, 
    suppliers.supplier_city,
    suppliers.supplier_country,
    (
        SELECT AVG(progress) 
        FROM answers 
        WHERE relevant = 1 AND audit_id = :audit_id AND rating != required_answer
    ) AS progress   --> here
FROM audit 
JOIN users ON audit.uid = users.id 
JOIN suppliers ON audit.supplier_id = suppliers.id 
JOIN questionaire ON audit.questionaire_id = questionaire.id 
WHERE 
    audit.cid = :cid 
    AND audit.general_audit_status = 'Maßnahmenplan'
    AND audit.assigned_auditor = :assigned_auditor"
```

Comment: Hey GMB, thank you for thiss. It removed the error but the result is 0. Looks like the method i echo the result is wrong? Thought it is now a part of the "$row"?

Comment: @MischaMilivojeBakic: it is part of `$row`, and available under index `progress`. If you get `0` then it means the the average is `0` for the parameters you passed to the query...

Comment: OK i found the issue. It is because i say in the array that :audit_id => 4. This i just took as test... Now comes the problem: The audi_ id is ta part of the query as you can see directly after the first SELECT. That means i cannot define ':audit_id' => $row['audit_id'] because it is still unknown. Is there a way to handle it with the alias (audit_id) ?

Comment: @Mischa Milivoje Bakic: Do you want the average for the audit in your main query? Are you looking for `AND audit_id = audit.id`?

Comment: Great guys! You helped me both out of this nightmare.

Soultion as prescribed by GMB and Thorsten: 

1. Move alias out of ()
2. audit_id = audit.id

Many thanks guys!